# Power BI: sharing Power BI apps with free users

Tags: powerbi

Just requiring some help and clarification around sharing Power BI apps.

We have an app created inside an EM1 premium capacity workspace, and we are wanting to share the app with user's within our organisation. My understanding is that if the app is published in a premium workspace all user's inside my organisation should be able to view it, providing it is shared with them.

However, only those of us with a pro license are able to view the app. Those with free licenses get a pop up message saying they'll need a pro license. No where online states this, hence my belief any user should be able to see the app.

We have given user's the "Viewer" role within the Power BI workspace, and even tried to give them admin role, neither let them see the app.

Can anyone clear this up/ help please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "Premium" is a bit of a mess, which isn't quite easy to clearly understand. In this case, you incorrectly assumed that "Premium" EM SKUs will give you rights to share contents with Power BI Free users - this is given only with "Premium" P SKUs. Quote from the [original docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-what-is#capacity-nodes):

> While there is a lot of overlap in features for the two SKU families, **only the P Premium SKU gives free users the ability to consume content hosted in the Premium capacity**. EM SKUs are used for embedding content.

If you want this, you must upgrade to P1 SKU (or higher), which is [7-8 times more expensive](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) and comes with [annual commitment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-faq#how-is-power-bi-premium-billed---).

Comment: What also makes it confusing is the doc's site also states: Users viewing a report in SharePoint need either a Power BI Pro or Premium Per User (PPU) license or the content needs to be in a workspace that's in a Power BI Premium capacity (EM or P SKU). So Apps might be out but workspaces are ok??